# Problem connecting to sqlite database in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have been having problems connecting to a database in my java application using sqlite.

I have already imported the jar file necessary (sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar) into my libraries.

Whenever I try to set and open the path to the database, I receive the following message:

```
Couldn't connect to database: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Info": syntax error)
```

Here is what the code looks like so far:

```
public static final String DB_FILE = "clients.db"


public static final String DB_PATH = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Steven/Documents/ProjectAnnieMalsRemote/Databases/" + DB_NAME;


//Sets a connection to access and utilize sqlite expressions, which are assigned to the PreparedStatement variables for later use
private Connection conn;

 public boolean open(){
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_PATH);
        insertIntoClientInfo = conn.prepareStatement(ClientInfoTable.getInsertClientInfo());
        insertIntoIncomeStatement = conn.prepareStatement(IncomeStatementTable.getInsertIncomeStatement());

        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't connect to database: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have tried all suggestions from this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348702/cant-connect-to-a-sqlite-database), but none of the solutions seem to work. I have also tried changing the paired slashes to single slashes in the path name, but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post a [mcve] and provide the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found out what the problem was. After doing a stack trace, I found that it was these two lines which were causing the problem

```
 insertIntoClientInfo = conn.prepareStatement(ClientInfoTable.getInsertClientInfo());
 insertIntoIncomeStatement = conn.prepareStatement(IncomeStatementTable.getInsertIncomeStatement());
```

So it was something to do with the prepareStatement methods that were causing a sqlite error and there was no problem with the connection itself.